# Python3 : Condition if else and count data with parse json

Tags: python, python-3.x

I've a JSON data file data.txt bellow :

```
{"Name": "Brian","scores": 8, "color": "red"}
{"Name": "Lina","scores": 2, "color": "blue"}
{"Name": "Brian","scores": 10, "color": "black"}
{"Name": "Brian","scores": 9, "color": "black"}
```

The json data as above JSON multiline in a file, I've code parse json decoded Object.

```
import json

studentsList = []

with open('data.txt') as f:
    for jsonObj in f:
        studentDict = json.loads(jsonObj)
        studentsList.append(studentDict)

for student in studentsList:
    if (student["Scores"]) >= 8:
        print(student["Name"],student["Color"])
```

Results:

```
Brian red
Brian black
Brian black
```

Question: Now I need to filter out information the result when variable "scores" >= 8 and other variables in the object counting up + 1 ?

Desire a result:

```
"Brian": 3 ,"black": 2 , "red": 1
```

Any ideas that can help me use on python3 .

Comment: Are these keys limited to just names and colors or will they change?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if the keys you've mentioned here will stay consistent for all cases but just to generalize the solution, we can include a list `keys` to keep track of all the values we want to include in the final output. 
This approach basically uses another hashmap `results` and counts the distinct values of all the variables mentioned in `keys`. 
This is a generalized solution, so if you want to include/exclude any of the values you can just update the list.

```
keys = ['Name', 'color']
results = {}
for student in studentsList:
    if (student["scores"]) >= 8:
        for i in keys:
            if results.get(student[i]) is not None:
                results[student[i]]+=1
            else:
                results[student[i]] = 1

         
print(results)
```

**Output**

```
{'Brian': 3, 'red': 1, 'black': 2}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your desired result is a dictionary, so let's create one

```
countObjects: Dict = {}
```

And then if search for the corresponding key, if it exists increment and if not create

```
for student in studentsList:
    if (student["Scores"]) >= 8:
      if student['Name'] in countObjects:
        countObjects[student['Name']] += 1
      else:
        countObjects[student['Name']] = 1
      print(student["Name"],student["Color"])
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `collections.Counter` to count the occurrences of each distinct value:

```
from collections import Counter

dict(Counter(i for d in studentsList if d.pop('scores') >= 8 for i in d.values()))
```

This returns:

```
{'Brian': 3, 'red': 1, 'black': 2}
```